# How to get blobs size through $MetricsCapacityBlob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to access $MetricsCapacityBlob (SO: [Azure Storage Table size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641890/azure-storage-table-size)) to see the total size of blobs on my azure account. This is what I have:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

var cloudTableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

var table = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference("$MetricsCapacityBlob");

var query = new TableQuery();
var result = table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();
```

Problem is, `result` is always 0 length. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh343264.aspx) sais storage capacity metrics are only updated once per day. So, if you have just enabled storage analytics and try this code, it will return 0 records. Meanwhile you can use any storage tool to check the Tables content and compare to your code to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Problem is, result is always 0 length. What am I doing wrong?

Your code looks OK to me. In fact I ran this code against this table in one of my storage accounts and it returned results. You could be getting no results back because there may be no data in the table. Did you create the storage account recently? Give it some time and data will show up.

**Alternate Solution**

Also, there's another way of working with Storage Analytics data and that is by using `AnalyticsClient` namespace in storage client library. See the sample code below which fetches the storage size for yesterday.

```
CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(StorageAccount, StorageAccountKey), true);
var client = account.CreateCloudAnalyticsClient();
var yesterday = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMddT0000");
var queryResult = client.CreateCapacityQuery().Where(q => q.PartitionKey == yesterday).ToList();
foreach (var item in queryResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.RowKey + " = " + item.Capacity);
}
```

Comment: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount' does not contain a definition for 'CreateCloudAnalyticsClient'. Am I missing something?

Comment: Which version of library are you using? This was introduced in one of the newer versions.

Comment: 2.1. I guess that's probably it.. 

Does the analytics client does anything other than pull data from the monitoring tables?

Comment: I would agree regarding the version. It was introduced in version 4.0.0.0 (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/changelog.txt#L47). Regarding `Does the analytics client does anything other than pull data from the monitoring tables?` - It takes care of deserialization of table data into proper entities which you would need to do it yourself if you use TableClient instead. HTH.

Comment: You mean SDK 2.5, right? Please check the version of storage client library in your project. It should be 4+.

Comment: The method CreateCloudAnalyticsClient is not available in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version 8.1.1.0. What are the alternate solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternate solution using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version 8.1.1.0 in Asp.NET Core 1.1.

```
CloudTableClient tableClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable metricsCapacityTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(Constants.AnalyticsConstants.MetricsCapacityBlob);

List<string> selectedColumns = new List<string>();
selectedColumns.Add("Capacity");

string yesterday = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMddT0000");
                
dataResult = await metricsCapacityTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Retrieve(yesterday, "data", selectedColumns));
                
DynamicTableEntity ddte = (DynamicTableEntity)dataResult.Result;
double? dataValueInBytes = ddte.Properties["Capacity"].Int64Value;
```