# Get Partition Size in Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I want to know the partition size before I try to extract all the data from it. if it's too big I would like to extract only some of the data - but in order to do that I need to know the size.
Is there any query doing that without actually pulling all the data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no query to retrieve Table partition size; you'd need to iterate through the table (or keep your own metadata about the table, as you add and remove entities over time).

There's a similar (though not quite duplicate) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13644528/272109) which is asking about the size of an entire table.